# C# how do I make my label from an label array disappear when clicked on?

Tags: c#, arrays, label

My code makes 5 labels appear with a random .Left location, you can see it.
I want the particular label to disappear when I click on it, but I don't know how to tell it to my click void.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Label [] kubeliai = new Label [5];
    int poz = 100;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < kubeliai.Length; i++)
        {
            kubeliai[i] = new Label();
            Controls.Add(kubeliai[i]);
            Random pos = new Random();
            kubeliai[i].Top = 50;
            kubeliai[i].Left = poz;
            poz += pos.Next(50, 200);
            kubeliai[i].BackColor = Color.Red;
            kubeliai[i].Height = 20;
            kubeliai[i].Width = 20;
            kubeliai[i].Click += new EventHandler(kubelio_clickas);
        }
    }
    void kubelio_clickas (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: sender parameter is a reference to the label clicked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share an event handler across multiple controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736807/share-an-event-handler-across-multiple-controls)

Comment: The `Random pos = new Random();` line should be **OUTSIDE** (and before) your `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object `sender` is a reference to the object which fired the event. So basically, the sender is the object you are looking for.

You just need to set it invisible:

```
((Label)sender).Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

The instance of "clicked" label is in `sender` parameter:

```
 void kubelio_clickas (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label clickedLabel = sender as Label;
        if (clickedLabel != null) {
           clickedLabel.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Because in .NET `Event Handlers` by default use object as type of `sender` you have to cast it to `Label` first.

Answer (score 1):

> I want the particular label to disappear when I click on it

Just set the label's `.Visible` property to false:

```
void kubelio_clickas (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is Label)
        ((Label)sender).Visible = false;
}
```