# Many buttons fire backgroundWorker

Tags: c#

In my application i have many buttons which fire functions via backgroundWorker
For example:

```
private void button26_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true){
                disableControls();
                backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
                backgroundWorker1.DoWork += (obj, ev) => addAuctionDraftToDb(getIdsFromAllegroColection("id"));
                backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged;
                backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }
```

Can i write shortly or set this to simple class because i have several dozen similar events which fire different functions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share an event handler across multiple controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736807/share-an-event-handler-across-multiple-controls).  BackgroundWorker is irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

Based on the operation name (`addAuctionDraftToDb`), you are trying to execute, this is  a IO operation.
Executing it on another thread will be waste of threads, because with IO operation, thread do nothing - only waiting for response from the remote resource.

You can get rid of `BackgroundWorker` by using asynchronous IO operations.

Rewrite database method to be asynchronous, for example

```
private async Task AddAuctionDraftToDb(List<int> draftIds)
{
    var query = "INSERT INTO ..";

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync();
        await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    }
}
```

Then in button click event handler you can write the code as usually without blocking UI during it's execution while everything will be ecuted on thesingle thread.
Notice `async void` signature of the event handler.

```
private async void button26_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Display something before execution

    var draftIds = getIdsFromAllegroColection("id");
    await AddAuctionDraftToDb(draftsId);

   // Display something when ready
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I do not mean about single writing or reading to database.. in every function there is a loop that gets data from API or database (one loop literation = one query) and showing results in datagridView in real time. For example get a few thousands product items from API server with describe, image etc. and show in datagrid in real Time